# using Linq to partition data into arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of elements where the element has a Flagged boolean value.

```
1 flagged
2 not flagged
3 not flagged
4 flagged
5 not flagged
6 not flagged
7 not flagged
8 flagged
9 not flagged
```

I want to break it into arrays based on the flagged indicator

output >

```
array 1 {1,2,3}
array 2 {4,5,6,7}
array 3 {8,9}
```

Answer (score 8):

Linq doesn't have an operator for this, but I've written an extension method that you may be able to use (in the process of submitting it to [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview), which you should also check out):

Using the operator below, you would write:

```
var result = 
   items.Segment( (item,prevItem,idx) => item.Flagged )
        .Select( seq => seq.ToArray() )  // converts each sequence to an array
        .ToList();
```

Here's the code of the extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Segment<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, T, int, bool> newSegmentIdentifier) 
     { 
         var index = -1; 
         using (var iter = sequence.GetEnumerator()) 
         { 
             var segment = new List<T>(); 
             var prevItem = default(T); 

             // ensure that the first item is always part 
             // of the first segment. This is an intentional 
             // behavior. Segmentation always begins with 
             // the second element in the sequence. 
             if (iter.MoveNext()) 
             { 
                 ++index; 
                 segment.Add(iter.Current); 
                 prevItem = iter.Current; 
             } 

             while (iter.MoveNext()) 
             { 
                 ++index; 
                 // check if the item represents the start of a new segment 
                 var isNewSegment = newSegmentIdentifier(iter.Current, prevItem, index); 
                 prevItem = iter.Current; 

                 if (!isNewSegment) 
                 { 
                     // if not a new segment, append and continue 
                     segment.Add(iter.Current); 
                     continue; 
                 } 
                 yield return segment; // yield the completed segment 

                 // start a new segment... 
                 segment = new List<T> { iter.Current }; 
             } 
             // handle the case of the sequence ending before new segment is detected 
             if (segment.Count > 0) 
                 yield return segment; 
         } 
     }
```

Comment: Why is the condition in the lambda function 'item.Flagged != prevItem.Flagged'? You would create a new segment if the flag changes from false to true. I think the condition should be just 'item.Flagged', and not dependant from the previous item at all.

Comment: @phild: You are correct, `item.Flagged` is sufficient. I was in a hurry earlier and misinterpreted the OP's expectations. I've updated my response.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with this, and solved it using `GroupBy` and closure.

```
//sample data
var arrayOfElements = new[] {
    new { Id = 1, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 2, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 3, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 4, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 5, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 6, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 7, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 8, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 9, Flagged = false }
};

//this is the closure which will increase each time I see a flagged
int flagCounter = 0;

var query = 
    arrayOfElements.GroupBy(e => 
        {
            if (e.Flagged)
                flagCounter++;
            return flagCounter;
        });
```

What it does is grouping on an int (`flagCounter`), which is increased each time a Flagged element is found.
Please note this won't work with `AsParallel()`.

Testing the results:

```
foreach(var group in query)
{
    Console.Write("\r\nGroup: ");
    foreach (var element in group)
        Console.Write(element.Id);
}
```

Outputs:

> Group: 123
>   Group: 4567
>   Group: 89

Comment: Very interesting approach. Very different to the other solutions, but you know, many roads lead to rome...

Comment: While interesting, I think it's kinda "hackish" to introduce state to the query. The end result, however, is nice (a linq grouping). Maybe there's a way to do it w/o the closure?

Comment: @Fábio: Closures are a great addition to C#, and are most suited for use in delegates (like in this case). My knowledge can't get me into a thread-safe solution using them yet, but surely this code is as readable as performant and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Considering:

```
var arrayOfElements = new[] {
    new { Id = 1, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 2, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 3, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 4, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 5, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 6, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 7, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 8, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 9, Flagged = false }
};
```

You can write:

```
var grouped = 
    from i in arrayOfElements
    where i.Flagged
    select 
        (new[] { i.Id })
        .Union(arrayOfElements.Where(i2 => i2.Id > i.Id).TakeWhile(i2 => !i2.Flagged).Select(i2 => i2.Id))
        .ToArray();
```

This works if your elements are ordered by the Id attribute. If they don't, you'll have to inject a Sequence on your original array, that should be easy to do with linq as well, so you'll get a sequence.

Also, a better alternative should be:

```
// for each flagged element, slice the array,
// starting on the flagged element until the next flagged element
var grouped = 
    from i in arrayOfElements
    where i.Flagged
    select 
        arrayOfElements
            .SkipWhile(i2 => i2 != i)
            .TakeWhile(i2 => i2 == i || !i2.Flagged)
            .Select(i2 => i2.Id)
            .ToArray();
```

Note that those answers are using pure linq.

Comment: I like Linq a lot, and use it where I can, but dont you think this is rather ugly compared to the classical approach (see my post)? I even think this is going to be worse in performance.

Comment: I evolved it a little bit, to remove the need to order them by Id. But I agree, it's worse on performance. I liked the @LBushkin answer, creating a new extension method for that.

Comment: +1 I like your second alternative. Nice to see how many tasks can be done with pure linq, that I would not even have thought about doing in linq.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think LINQ is the right tool for this task. What about this:

```
public static List<List<T>> PartitionData<T>(T[] arr, Func<T, bool> flagSelector){
    List<List<T>> output = new List<List<T>>();
    List<T> partition = null;
    bool first = true;

    foreach(T obj in arr){
        if(flagSelector(obj) || first){
            partition = new List<T>();
            output.Add(partition);
            first = false;
        }
        partition.Add(obj);
    }

    return output;
}
```

A small example, with the Data from Fábio Batistas post:

```
var arrayOfElements = new[] {
    new { Id = 1, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 2, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 3, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 4, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 5, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 6, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 7, Flagged = false },
    new { Id = 8, Flagged = true },
    new { Id = 9, Flagged = false }
};

var partitioned = PartitionData(arrayOfElements, x => x.Flagged);
```

Comment: I think this needs a output.Add(currentList); after the foreach statement, or your last array never gets added.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think LINQ is suited for this very well.  It could be done with Aggregate() but I think you'd be better of just looping with a foreach() building up the result.